# Is there a spell that can permanently freeze an area?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items

Is there any spell or magic item effect that can permanently freeze an area? (Freeze as in ice and snow).

Comment: Can you provide more info on exactly what you want it to do? What final effects are you looking for? What does "freeze an area" mean?

Comment: When you say "permanent", do you want the spell/item to maintain it magically regardless of prevailing conditions, or permanent as in it will be real solid ice but still subject to melting in the sun?

Comment: And how big of an area are you wanting?

Comment: Tags should be used to describe the question, not the potential answers. Also, could you clarify what kind of effect you're looking for?

Comment: *Do you want to build a snowman?* Seriously does the DM have buy-in on doing this / satisfies the Rule of Cool?

Comment: And of course as with any question "is there a spell that can...", one answer is "Wish, possibly".

Comment: [How can one create a permanent walk-through-portal to another location?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/137910/how-can-one-create-a-permanent-walk-through-portal-to-another-location)

Answer (score 24):

#### The *Ring of Winter*, a powerful legendary artifact from *Tomb of Annihilation*, can permanently freeze areas (12 x 120 foot areas per day)

Since you mentioned "magic item effect", there's the *Ring of Winter*, a powerful legendary artifact from *Tomb of Annihilation*, which has the following in its stat block:

> ***Magic.*** The *Ring of Winter* has 12 charges and regains all its expended charges daily at dawn. While wearing the ring, you can expend the necessary number of charged to activate one of the following properties:
>
> - You can expend 1 charge as an action and use the ring to lower the temperature in a 120-foot-radius sphere centered on a point you can see within 300 feet of you. The temperature in that area drops 20 degrees per minute, to a minimum of -30 degrees Fahrenheit. **Frost and ice begin to form on surfaces once the temperature drops below 32 degrees. This effect is permanent** unless you use the ring to end it as an action, at which point the temperature in the areas returns to normal at a rate of 10 degrees per minute.

That feature seems to be what you're after, but if you want something on a larger scale:

> ***Other Properties.*** The *Ring of Winter* is rumored to possess other properties that can be activated only by an evil being whose will the ring can't break. Frost giants have long believed that the ring can be used to **freeze entire worlds**, [...]

Although that last one is just hearsay, essentially, but the fact that it has been included in the stat block at least implies that it's possible to rule, as a DM, that it can do such things.

[image]

Comment: Given the first quote, achieving the second quote seems to be only a matter of time

Comment: a LOT of time though, each hit covers 0.004 square kilometers but there will be overlap between the areas if you want to cover everything since circles don't tessalate the plane. At 12 charges per day lets say you get about 0.04 square kilometers per day after overlap is accounted for. That is about 15 square kilometers per year or about 34 million years to freeze the earth.

Comment: A hypothesis says that Antarctica isn't cold because it doesn't receive enough sunlight, but because that's the place where ancient scientists were testing the precise definition of a day used by the Ring of Winter.

Answer (score 10):

### The best I can come up* with is *[control weather](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/control-weather)*, but it's temporary

<sup>* regarding spells; see [my other answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/164448/35259) regarding magic items...</sup>

This is an 8th level spell that lasts for 8 hours, and allows you to control the weather within a 5 mile radius of your position, so long as you can see the sky for that duration (else the spell ends early).

From the PHB (p. 228):

> **You take control of the weather within 5 miles of your for the duration**. You must be outdoors to cast this spell. Moving to a place where you don't have a clear path to the sky ends the spell early.
>
> Wen you cast the spell, you change the current weather conditions, which are determined by the DM based on the climate and season. **You can change precipitation, temperature** and wind. It takes 1d4 x 10 minutes for the new conditions to take effect. **Once they do so, you can change the conditions again**. When the spell ends, the weather gradually returns to normal.
>
> **When you change the weather conditions**, find a current condition on the following tables and **change its stage by one, up or down.** [...]

It then lists tables of precipitation, ranging from "Clear" to "Torrential rain, driving hail, or **blizzard**", temperature, between "Unbearable heat" and "**Arctic cold**", and wind, from "Calm" to "Storm".

Unless the area is already quite cold, you will have to change the weather step-by-step to get to Arctic cold, but I imagine a few hours of that, especially if you add a blizzard, should freeze most areas temporarily.

I guess if you had a circle of high level druids who all took it in turns to cast it every 8 hours, then you could create an indefinitely temporary tundra, which is as close to permanent as this spell is going to get...

Answer (score 10):

### *[Mirage Arcane](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/mirage-arcane)* is an option.

Although Mirage Arcane produces an illusion of the desired, frozen terrain, the illusion:

> includes audible, visual, tactile, and olfactory elements

Tactile elements would include the cold of the ice, frigid winds, etc, and even creatures that can see through the illusion would still feel those elements.

Although the duration of this spell is only 10 days, and not indefinite, any caster able to cast it (notably Bards, Druids, and Wizards) regains their spell slots on a long rest.  Since you can take a long rest every 24 hours, you could keep up the frozen terrain by recasting Mirage Arcane on the area once every 10 days.

Comment: A DM could remix the rule for teleport circles and other things that if you cast the spell repeatedly for a sufficiently long time, it becomes permanent, at least until someone casts 'dispel magic'.

Answer (score 7):

***Shape Water*** from *Xanathar's Guide to Everything* lets you freeze 2 small areas for 1 hour, 5x5x5 feet each. It's a cantrip. (XGE p.164)
Depending on the size you want, you can have a bunch of elves who took the cantrip racial ability, or first level wizards fill a space.
As a Canadian, I assume you are building a hockey rink?