# How do I become permanently Large-sized?

Tags: dnd-5e, creature-size, warforged

I am currently an 8-foot-tall juggernaut Warforged fighter in D&D 5e. How can I get to the size category Large permanently (i.e., 9 feet tall)?

There are only two ways I have found so far and that is to be a Wild Magic sorcerer, and with *wish*. But, I am only 9th level, so I cannot use *wish*. And as stated before, I am a fighter. So I do not know any spells, but I do have my technical “creator” in my party.

Comment: Related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/84010/can-wild-magic-growth-make-me-a-large-creature

Comment: Thanks for clarifying what you're playing. I've reopened. Welcome to RPG Stack Exchange, and check out our [tour] to see how we work here. When you reach 20 rep you'll also be welcome to join us in [chat].

Comment: It is unclear whether changing your height via Wild Magic Surge automatically changes your size. See [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/84010/41726) (and in particular the top two voted answers).

Answer (score 13):

### Sorry, by RAW, what you've called out in your question is pretty much it.

One of the big shifts that 5E has taken is that making permanent magical changes to something is *hard.*

In 3.5E, you could use (or have someone else use) the 5th level spell Permanancy to cast a permanent version of Enlarge Person on you. As of 5E, that spell has (at least for now) been [left out of the game](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/64321/what-happened-to-the-permanency-spell). On top of that, there are very few canon magical items that imbue you with a permanent spell-like-effect, and none of them impact Size.

At this point, if you really want to make a permanent jump to Large size, you'll need to work with your DM to come up on a solution. Perhaps some Cannith Artificer is willing to upgrade your Chassis to Juggernaut-class...perhaps you can find a magic item that does it. Perhaps you run into an Eldritch Machine (read: MacGuffin) that has that effect.

In short, there is no easy RAW solution that will work for you if you don't get lucky on the Wild Magic table (which could just as easily reduce you back out of Large Size, or even smaller) or Wish (which can by wildly unreliable depending on your DM). If your heart is set on this, talk to your DM and see if you can come to a solution together.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that have a Large PC would be a significant increase in power that I as a DM would likely not allow outside of wish (or other risky RAW options) because of balance implications.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose or a significant decrease if large monster rules aren't used (more creatures can surround you). It's very hard to judge

Comment: The other option is *true polymorph*, if the asker is willing to give up all his current game statistics for a new form.

Comment: @V2Blast I left that one out because he seems to be interested in continuing to be a Warforged Fighter...

Comment: May be worth noting that Wild Magic's height increase does not inherently change your size to Large by RAW. It just ups your height, but anyone change in size would have to come from DM fiat.

Answer (score 13):

[Mixing potions](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/treasure#VariantMixingPotions) has a 1% chance of making one of the potion effects permanent (DMG, p. 140).  If you drink a [*Potion of Growth*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/potion-of-growth) (DMG, p. 187) along with another potion, there is a small chance that it could become permanent.

Also, as Bloodcinder pointed out in a comment, this is an optional rule. It is up to the DM whether to implement this rule.

Comment: Fair warning, other side effects include explosions, turning into poison, negating effects, etc. Most of which you can only determine by chugging the potion. Attempt with caution. :)

Comment: @guildsbounty: That's what healing magic is for. As long as the negatives are temporary and survivable, and the positives are permanent, it's just a matter of money and time to get the desired effect. :-) Just make sure the potion you're mixing with is "more complex" (whatever that means) or "less fun" than the *Potion of Growth*, since the rules says "Choose the simplest effect to make permanent, or the one that seems the most fun".

Answer (score 2):

### Bigby Presents: Glory of the Giants, Path of the Giant Barbarian

> 3rd-Level Path of the Giant Feature
> Your rages pull strength from the primal might of giants, transforming you into a hulking force of destruction. While raging, you gain the following benefits:
> ...
> **Giant Stature. Your reach increases by 5 feet, and if you are smaller than Large, you become Large, along with anything you are wearing. If there isn’t enough room for you to increase your size, your size doesn’t change.**

Additionally, at 20th level, you have unlimited rages.

This isn't exactly what you were looking for, but I would suggest that you change your vision to a controllable, temporary increase in size as often as you want it. It doesn't have to be from the Barbarian, but that is my suggestion. This is because a large size can be a sizable detriment to you due to the [squeeze mechanic](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/76158/83144). With examples like the Path of the Giant Barbarian, you can have most of the benefits of being large, or even huge at 14th level, with little of the drawbacks.

Lastly, since you seem to be going for a more brutish focus, using a martial class instead of a magical one should fit your aim more, instead of going for enlarge/reduce or potion-making.

Comment: Hello Mr. Banner. May I ask you not to turn green from anger?