# How to reduce the size of the Ancient Companion from the UA Mage of Lorehold subclass?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, unearthed-arcana, creature-size, permanency

The description of the Mage of Lorehold's Ancient Companion feature (from [UA: Mages of Strixhaven](https://media.wizards.com/2021/dnd/downloads/UA2021_06_08_MagesStrixhaven.pdf)) reads, in part:

> Whenever you finish a short or long rest, you can call forth and bond with one such spirit, who comes to **inhabit a Medium, freestanding statue** within 10 feet of you to serve as your ancient companion.

**What are the ways by which I can reduce the size of my Ancient Companion, either temporarily or (preferably) permanently?**

Ideas I've come up with so far:

- Cast [Enlarge/Reduce](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Enlarge%20Reduce#pageAttrs) on it
- Use [Wish](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Wish#pageAttrs) (the risky way) to cast [Enlarge/Reduce](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Enlarge%20Reduce#pageAttrs) on it, making the size change permanent
- Have it drink a [Potion of Diminution](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Potion%20of%20Diminution#pageAttrs)
- Have it drink a [Potion of Diminution](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Potion%20of%20Diminution#pageAttrs) together with another potion which gives a 1% chance to make the effect permanent ([source](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/128827/76172))

Ideally I would like my Ancient Companion to be able to attune to a magic item that just shrinks it by one or two size categories, but I haven't found anything suitable so far...

Comment: When you mention using *wish*, are you talking about a custom worded *wish*?

Comment: Yes, I updated the question to make that clear

Comment: Is there a reason why you want it smaller? Just curious.

Comment: @SeriousBri I can think of lots of reasons a familiar type companion would be more useful if it were smaller than me.

Comment: @SeriousBri only the most noble reason of all reasons: its cuter  I really like the idea of being able to carve myself a small wooden statue and animate it into a talking, walking, self thinking companion. If the statue grows a bit in size thats fine, but if it gets as tall as I am boy will it be hard to get all the details right

Comment: This feels like it could get hairy fast - especially since there's precedent (not official rulings) about [whether spells and effects end/suppress when a target is no longer valid](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/103845/can-polymorph-end-spells-that-require-the-target-to-be-humanoid). This is clearly different, but I feel it can have similar rulings.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Do it the other way round

Shortly before the end of your long rest, cast *enlarge* on a Small freestanding statue. It will be a Medium freestanding statue for the duration (concentration, 1 minute). End the rest and have the spirit inhabit the statue. You now have a Medium Ancient Companion construct. End concentration on *enlarge*. The construct reverts to small size, and remains small thereafter.

(You may want to check with your DM if they are fine with this. The stat block after all says Medium construct; but in particular, if this is mainly because you think it is more cute, and not to capture some unfair advantage, it should be fine.)

Comment: Such a creative way  I really love this idea!

Comment: If you are casting while resting, you are not actually resting? This is getting into some questionable mechanical interpretation of the resting mechanics for a mostly cosmetic change. If it then still hinges on a DM decision, it doesn't seem to be worth it to come up with this contrived way of arriving at the result.

Comment: @J.E There is no need for a DM decision on that - you [can cast while long resting](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/110485/75095) just fine.

Comment: @NobodytheHobgoblin Thanks, I forgot about that rule, (well, it's not that you can cast spells while resting, it's that you can get back to resting after interruption if it is less than 1 hour) but still, you are resting, then you suspend the rest, cast it, get back to rest for another *50 seconds*, then end the rest. That's what I mean by questionably mechanical.

Comment: @J.E Thanks, I think I understand what you mean. There is even a [question about how legitimate this is](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/198324/75095), if not from a rules perspetive (which allows it), from a in-universe perspective.

Comment: @NobodytheHobgoblin I have actually read that Q/A (it's linked in a comment on that previous one), but IMO this is "exploiting" a different bit of the mechanic; not the save spell slots part but the strictly mechanical end of rest bit. For this to work, the *you can call forth and bond with one such spirit* procedure has to take less than a minute. If the spirit answers your call a minute late, *enlarge* is over. It hinges on the the timings of finishing a rest and doing this not being specified and considering resting a mechanical on/off state.

Answer (score 8):

### Ask your DM nicely

Since you are already using UA content I am assuming this isn't a strict RAW table and the DM is at least partially open to homebrew and house rules. As such and combined with your comment that you want it mostly for flavour I would just ask if they would let you have a small companion instead of a medium one. There was a question about advantages of Small and Medium PCs and from what I remember it boiled down to very minor aspects, most of which won't be relevant in this case anyway. So I think it's a very reasonable request that most DMs would just grant without making you jump through needless hoops.

Comment: This is exactly why I asked the question about why they wanted it, exactly the right way to go about this kind of thing.